# DateTime on signature field

Tags: cosign-api

I am signing pdf files from my company's custom Oracle forms system
using Cosign SAPI, including a secure timestamp, provided by an authorized secure timestamp server. Ntp Server is configured on cosign.

Date and time (correct local time - zone) are embedded succesfully on the signed pdf file.

Problem comes with the visible digital signature field-(on the top right corner of the pdf file), where time is always set on the wrong time zone (gmt-7).

Any workaround as to set time on the visible signature field provided by timestamp server on LOCAL timezone?

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a screenshot of the signed pdf.
Time is embeded on the correct local time zone on the signed pdf (GMT+3).Time is also embeded correclty on the visible digital signature field, **but** on the wrong-not desired- timezone (GMT-7).

[See the Print Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nw79c.png)

Answer (score 0):

The time on the visible signature field is set according to the time zone of the signing machine.
Is it possible that although the client machine is located in Greece, the signing machine is physically located in the US West coast (or at least the time zone of the signing machine is set to PST)?
What application are you using for signing? Web App or anything else?

Comment: No both client and cosign are located in Greece. Greek NTP server is set on cosign as well. Custom oracle forms app  & Cosign SAPI is used for signing. How can someone change cosign timezone???? 

"The time zone offset (“-0800” in Figure 72) cannot be updated and is displayed for informational purposes only." says on administrator's guide.